# ASP.net core display variable in an img tag for src

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to use a variable that I set in my controller to be the src inside of an img tag.  I copied the string in directly and it worked so I know my path is correct.  However, I am having trouble figuring out how to place the variable I create into the img tag.

Here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace dojodachi.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /Home/
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Tree"] = "~/images/regular_tree.jpeg";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my cshtml file

```
<div id = wrapper>
    <p>Fullness:    Happiness:      Meals:     Energy</p>
    <div id = inside>
        <img src="@ViewData['Tree']" alt="Regular Tree"> //How do I place my variable in this img tag?
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using MVC (Model View Controller)... how come you don't have a model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use single quotes on the outside and double quotes on the property:

`<img src='@ViewData["Tree"]'`

If you are using C# 4 you could also use `ViewBag` instead of `ViewData`.

On controller:

`ViewBag.Tree = "~/images/regular_tree.jpeg";`

Then on view:

`<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.Tree)"`

Comment: Thanks, but now for some reason I am getting a 404 error.  When I hard code the string in the image shows up, but when I use a variable I get a 404 error

Comment: @Aaron If you set the url on the controller with the server relative `~` then use `Url.Content` to resolve the URL during view rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but having similar issue today, so maybe can help others, solved as follow:

Controller:

```
ViewData["Tree"] = "images/regular_tree.jpeg";
```

View:

```
<img src="~/@ViewBag.Tree">
```